# Can we add custom column index in Jquery datatable instead of default 0, 1, 2?

Tags: jquery, datatable

I am using jquery datatable 1.9 version. I am preparing my table columns dynamically which comes from database and has unique id. I want to assign that unique id in database as an index to datatable columns so that I could easily map backend result sets with the column index.

Is there any way to assign custom index. By default it take 0, 1, 2 etc.

I have already reffered documentation but couldnt find any parameter to assign index

http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/columns#mData

Comment: I didn't get it, assign custom index to what..? isn't it easier to structure the data appropriately? have you check this [example](http://www.datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html)?

Comment: column index by default are 0, 1, 2 etc. I want to assign custom ids e.g. primary keys from db, it could be 2, 5, 9, anything. I need it because when we click on column to sort, it sends index of column in request, we need to figure out to which database column index maps to.  It become easier and faster to map if I can use primary keys as an index. My columns are not static, they are dynamic defined by user as user can create their own views